# The same program again

Tags: python, pygame, pixel

I asked a question about this program yesterday but i have come across another problem.
The code still runs and thinks it is colouring in pixels but it should stop when the bottom of the page is reached, it does not.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame,sys, random, time
y = 0
x = 0
keepgoing = True
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pixel = raw_input('Please enter a NUMBER that goes into 500. ')
end = 500-(int(pixel))
int(pixel)
screen.fill((255,255,255))

while keepgoing:
    print x,y
    r = random.randint(0,255)
    g = random.randint(0,255)
    b = random.randint(0,255)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (r,g,b),(x,y,int(pixel),int(pixel)))
    if x >= end:
        x = 0
        y += int(pixel)
        r = random.randint(0,255)
        g = random.randint(0,255)
        b = random.randint(0,255)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (r,g,b),(x,y,int(pixel),int(pixel)))
    if x == end and y == end:
        print 'done'
        keepgoing == False
        break
    x += (int(pixel))

    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit();



for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

you will see what i mean if you run the code in python IDLE.

Comment: Can't you do a nested for-loop and cycle through x-pixels and y-pixels?

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify what's your problem. When you say _the same problem again_, how can we know what you mean?

Comment: @Bonifacio2 he says "The same **program** again"

Comment: -1 for a really terrible question title.

Comment: @RickyA useless as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if x >= end:
```

To:

```
if x >= end and y <= end:
```

Also, change:

```
    keepgoing == False
```

To:

```
    keepgoing = False
```

Also, consider changing:

```
if x == end and y == end:
```

To:

```
if x >= end and y >= end:
```

Note:  You should probably use a **nested for-loop** and cycle through x-pixels and y-pixels.  It may be better than using a **while-loop**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `for` loop?

```
from itertools import product
for x, y in product(range(end), repeat=2):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keepgoing == False
```

`==` does a comparison check. You want

```
keepgoing = False
```